# Как изменить форму массива изображения в Numpy Python. Ошибка: "Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape ..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Не могу разобраться где изменить форму массива - вначале выставляю но перед обучением нейронная сеть все равно получает массив не той формы

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D 
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
# Каталог с данными для обучения 
train_dir = 'train' 
# Каталог с данными для проверки 
val_dir = 'val' 
# Каталог с данными для тестирования 
test_dir = 'test' 
# Размеры изображения 
img_width, img_height = 28, 28 
# Размерность тензора на основе изображения для входных данных в нейронную сеть 
# backend Tensorflow, channels_last 
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 1) 
# Количество эпох 
epochs = 30 
# Размер мини-выборки 
batch_size = 1
# Количество изображений для обучения 
nb_train_samples = 1690 
# Количество изображений для проверки 
nb_validation_samples = 368 
# Количество изображений для тестирования 
nb_test_samples = 358 
print (input_shape)
# Создаем последовательную модель 
model = Sequential() 

model.add(Conv2D(75, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu',         input_shape=input_shape)) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
model.add(Conv2D(100, (5, 5), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
# Компилируем модель 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory( 
train_dir, 
target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
batch_size=batch_size, 
class_mode='categorical')
val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory( 
val_dir, 
target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
batch_size=batch_size, 
class_mode='categorical')
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory( 
test_dir, 
target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
batch_size=batch_size, 
class_mode='categorical')
model.fit_generator( 
train_generator, 
steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size, 
epochs=epochs, 
validation_data=val_generator, 
validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
Epoch 1/30 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------— 
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-10-3bb64fd7de71> in <module>() 
4 epochs=epochs, 
5 validation_data=val_generator, 
----> 6 validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size) 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in         wrapper(*args, **kwargs) 
85 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + 
86 '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2) 
---> 87 return func(*args, **kwargs) 
88 wrapper._original_function = func 
89 return wrapper 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in             fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks,         validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers,     use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch) 
1154 use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, 
1155 shuffle=shuffle, 
-> 1156 initial_epoch=initial_epoch) 
1157 
1158 @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in     wrapper(*args, **kwargs) 
85 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + 
86 '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2) 
---> 87 return func(*args, **kwargs) 
88 wrapper._original_function = func 
89 return wrapper 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in     fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks,         validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers,     use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch) 
2075 outs = self.train_on_batch(x, y, 
2076 sample_weight=sample_weight, 
-> 2077 class_weight=class_weight) 
2078 
2079 if not isinstance(outs, list): 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in         train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight) 
1789 sample_weight=sample_weight, 
1790 class_weight=class_weight, 
-> 1791 check_batch_axis=True) 
1792 if self.uses_learning_phase and not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int): 
1793 ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1.] 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in     _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,     check_batch_axis, batch_size) 
1407 self._feed_input_shapes, 
1408 check_batch_axis=False, 
-> 1409 exception_prefix='input') 
1410 y = _standardize_input_data(y, self._feed_output_names, 
1411 output_shapes, 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in     _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix) 
152 ' to have shape ' + str(shapes[i]) + 
153 ' but got array with shape ' + 
--> 154 str(array.shape)) 
155 return arrays 
156 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 28, 28, 1) but got array with shape (1, 28, 28, 3)
```

Comment: у вас изображения на входе в градациях серого? можете указать размерность одной картинки?

Comment: Да, размерность должна быть - (1, 28, 28, 1)

Comment: судя по ошибке `got array with shape (1, 28, 28, 3)` у вас есть и цветные (с тремя каналами) картинки...

Comment: В том то и дело что все картинки черно-белые

Comment: можете выложить ваш `data set`, чтобы можно было воспроизвести?

Comment: Пожалуйста - https://yadi.sk/d/ryfHmncs3VSvFZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вызвана [генератором картинок - `datagen.flow_from_directory(...)`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), который по умолчанию генерирует цветные (`RGB`) картинки, т.е. на выходе вы получаете 3-х канальные картинки, а ваша модель ожидает на входе одноканальные (в градациях серого) картинки.

[Из документации](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

> **color_mode:** one of `"grayscale"`, `"rbg"`.
>
> Default: `"rgb"`. Whether the images will be converted to have 1 or 3
>   color channels.

чтобы исправить:

```
train_generator = \
datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, 
                            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                            color_mode='grayscale',               # <--- NOTE!
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            class_mode='categorical')
```

PS параметр `color_mode='grayscale'` надо добавить для всех генераторов...

Comment: Помогло, спасибо !!!